# How is possible to change size(width and height) of the component in codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to add some component to the form such as: button, label and more.
And i want to set width and height to them but i don't find such a property.
Is there any way to do that?

edit:

here is my code in Main.java file

```
currentForm = new Form();

currentForm.setLayout(new LayeredLayout());

currentForm.applyRTL(true);
Container mapContainer = new Container(new LayeredLayout());
Container controlsContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
controlsContainer.setRTL(true);
currentForm.addComponent(mapContainer);
currentForm.addComponent(controlsContainer);

Container panelTop = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
Container panelDown = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.RIGHT));
panelTop.setSize(new Dimension(40, 20));

controlsContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, panelTop);
controlsContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panelDown);

Button btnRoute = new Button(res.getImage("icon_routing.png"));
btnRoute.setSize(new Dimension(5, 5));
TextField txtSearch = new TextField();
txtSearch.setRTL(true);
txtSearch.setUIID("searchbox");
txtSearch.setEnabled(true);
// search textfield mode
txtSearch.putClientProperty("searchField", Boolean.TRUE);
txtSearch.setSize(new Dimension(8,10));
Button btnGPSFound = new Button(res.getImage("near_by_menu.png"));
btnGPSFound.setSize(new Dimension(5,5));

panelTop.addComponent(btnRoute);
panelTop.addComponent(txtSearch);
panelTop.addComponent(btnGPSFound);

currentForm.show();
btnRoute.setSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
btnRoute.refreshTheme();
panelTop.refreshTheme();     `
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your layout manager of choice, the layout manager determines the sizes of the components in runtime based on many constraints including the preferred layout. Some layout managers ignore some preferred layout values (this depends on several things).

To see the layout manager options see: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---positioning-components-using-layout-managers.html

To determine a desired size which will be taken into consideration by some layout managers use `setPreferredSize()`.

Comment: I have a scenario in which this does not work, however according to the API it should: I have a border layout which contains a container with a variable number of entries in the SOUTH constraint. setting the preferred height of the container works well, as long as the container is not scrollable.


`recentSearchContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  recentSearchContainer.setPreferredH((int)(this.getContentPane().getHeight() * 0.1f));`


Once setting the container scrollable, the preferred height is ignored. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Scrollable containers have their own sizing logic, I suggest filing a question with a proper description and screenshots of your end goal

Answer (score 1):

You can set width and height by calling `setSize(width, height)` on the component.

Comment: Is there another way to give component width and height in codenameone designer?

Comment: I change the size of component with setSize but it still doesn't   changed can you give me an simple example

Comment: I see that you are setting the size of `btnRoute` twice. Have you tried to set new size (30, 30) only once and before you call `show()`? Otherwise, try to do a repaint on the form object.

Comment: yeah none of them worked :| every thing i give them they give their default value not mine

Comment: Ok. Try to do a repaint on the form object.

Comment: I use revalidate and repaint and none of them are working. i just become really confused.

Comment: If nothing else is working, try to do it from scratch. For example, delete (comment out) the button and check if it disappears. Then do small changes, step by step. Or debug your code and run one line of code, one at a time.

Comment: This won't work since the layout manager will overwrite that value.